# XNA Farseer Physics Troubles

Tags: c#, xna, physics, farseer

So I have a game object and I create a body by loading in a texture from file and converting it:

```
            Texture2D polygonTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(Game.graphicsDevice, File.OpenRead(filepath));
            uint[] data = new uint[polygonTexture.Width * polygonTexture.Height];
            polygonTexture.GetData(data);

            //convert it to a polygon
            Vertices textureVertices = PolygonTools.CreatePolygon(data, polygonTexture.Width, false);
            Vector2 centroid = -textureVertices.GetCentroid();
            textureVertices.Translate(ref centroid);
            Vector2 origin = -centroid;
            textureVertices = SimplifyTools.ReduceByDistance(textureVertices, 4f);
            List<Vertices> list = BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartition(textureVertices);
            Vector2 vertScale = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(1));
            foreach (Vertices vertices in list)
            {
                vertices.Scale(ref vertScale);
            }

            //creat the body from the verticies
            Body compound = BodyFactory.CreateCompoundPolygon(Game.world, list, 1f, BodyType.Dynamic);
            compound.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

            //set the object's verticies to the polygon and the texture to its image
            obj.body = compound;
```

And then I draw it like this in my draw event:

```
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(bgColor);
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null,     null, null, camera2D.get_transformation(graphicsDevice));

    obj.body.Position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    spriteBatch.Draw(polygonTexture,
    ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(obj.body.Position),
                        null,
                        obj.tint,
                        obj.body.Rotation,
                        Vector2.Zero, 1f,
                        SpriteEffects.None,
                        obj.layer);

            spriteBatch.End();
```

The image doesn't show up at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I highly recommend you turn on the DebugView, included in the Farseer release.  It will give you a better view of what is happening with your code.  Farseer is completely independent of your drawing code.